# Typescript get names of fields but not properties (or at least get only)

Tags: typescript, types, properties

I know in typescript I can do this, to get the names of properties:

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
```

This worked great: ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nYBLCBnAPAFQHxQC8sqAxgNa4A0UA3lANoDSUqAdlORCAgGZQ4AugC4BzQVAgAPYBDYATDFABiAVzak0CDgH4obCADcIcKKJYBfBlx78heANwAoXus2ptUDCdQBDADaoAF4QuJIycopQABS+AEYYwHC+mvoQAO4xAHQ5vnAA5hiivmwgAJREBCXleNHAojg0CHEAVqLwSCZomFgAkmyJJaQQOOCh+Hhlov2DGiNjuHhO9HAQwKpwHADyrRCaWb4YGKj5bNE7LXvAWaSrvrJ1WWCIwAigkGVNrRUWTk6k-kOSgAalcEHAAEzLJxQWFQUjaRJwVSacExMCqOKBUhQAAaojYqgAtnETEQoAAGGgYrFkKAATQJxNJpmIuIq9F+MLhAFlVP40GB-CBokSmSSTFMoKDUZC6FBVutNmlMjLXpC6gALVAYLK4qAAKigRJowG1uvphuNP25sIAMnJ8mbolLCRLTLRFRsODz7pqshgAI4oLU6vVWs1h-UAaigkYtEfNWXpNq5-jWUE1vjAYBAMvJBlVYI1AGYaAAWMrOBEDBDprL+BD5aJZnN5vZZB1sJ2al1Vpyt3P54iD9ukLJ8gWoIUikv9msYOsQBtNlvZocdrs9vvOUfDrw+ALBCDRNXgiE0Wg5LJ7vY0fFQACsFirUAA9G-M+ux+HiI-q4iS4rs2t7jluzplFWQA))

My only problem was when I changed my methods to properties ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nYBLCBnAPAFQHxQC8sqAxgNa4A0UA3lANoDSUqAdlORCAgGZQ4AugC4BzQVAgAPYBDYATDFABiAVzak0CDgH4obCADcIcKKJYBfBlx78heANwAoXus2ptUDCdQBDADaoAF4QuJIycopQABS+AEYYwHC+mvoQAO4xAHQ5vnAA5hiivmwgAJREBCXleNHAojg0CHEAVqLwSCZomFgAkmyJJaQQOOCh+Hhlov2DGiNjuHhO9HAQwKpwHADyrRCaWb4YGKj5bNE7LXvAWaSrvrJ1WWCIwAigkGVNrRUWTk6k-kOSgAalcEHAAEzLJxQWFQUjaRJwVSacExMCqOKBUhQAAaojYqgAtnETEQoAAGGgYrFkKAATQJxNJpmIuIq9F+MLhAFlVP40GB-CBokSmSSTFMoKDUZC6FBVutNmlMjLXpC6gALVAYLK4qAAKigRJowG1uvphuNP25sPyaygABk5PkzdEpYSJaZaIqNhwefdNVkMABHFBanV6q1myP6gDUUBjFuj5qy9JtXP8Ds1vjAYBAMvJBlVYI1AGYaAAWMrOBEDBBZrL+BD5aI5vMFvZZZ1sV2amtOdv5wvEIed0hZPkC1BCkVlgd1jANiBNltt3PDrs9vsDscjrw+ALBCDRNXgiE0Wg5LJ7vY0fFQACsFhrUAA9G+oLeJ-riI-a4iy6rq237di6Zo1kAA)): (

```
Length(): number {return Math.sqrt(this.X * this.X + this.Y * this.Y) }
```

to

```
get Length(): number {return Math.sqrt(this.X * this.X + this.Y * this.Y) }
```

)Is there a way to exclude get-only properties or properties in general?

What I would need would be something like:

```
T[K] extends (GetOnlyProperty | Function)
```

instead of

```
T[K] extends Function
```